# Silence login info when not using a display manager

Tags: linux, nix, nixos

I want to silence the login info provided in tty after the boot-log/boot-screen  and drop me directly to shell. What I get after the boot-screen is complete.

```
Run 'nixos-help' for the NixOS manual.
CosPi login: creator54 (automatic login)
```

after this I get a shell prompt.
I know I could just add a `clear` on topmost of my shell config, but it takes some time to reach the shell after the boot-log/boot-screen is complete and the OS gets stuck in this info for few(~15) seconds. So adding `clear` does't do much here as i'll still see the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control what files the home of the user you are logging in contains, you can disable the messages by adding the file .hushlogin to the home directory. It does not have to contain anything, just do

```
touch .hushlogin
```

(I have not used this on NixOS, but this .hushlogin is a very old feature that works on other Linux distributions, and also on Solaris, FreeBSD etc).

Comment: I did try this, but it did't seem to have any effect. (created ~/.hushlogin)

Comment: You sure the .hushlogin file was created at the _remote_ end? If it did not help, you just have to examine NixOS-specific documentation. Maybe it does login differently. Unfortunately I don't have experience with NixOS, just various other Linux distributions. One other thing is that in most systems, much of the message that is printed at login comes from the file /etc/motd. Removing or making it empty might make the message shorter (but again, NixOS might do something different here).